# If $N$ satisfies $\mu^{*}(N) = 0$, is it a null set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

In measure theory, one starts with a measure $\mu_{0}$ on an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ (of subsets of $X$) and then defines an outer measure $\mu^{*}$ on $2^{X}$. Then, one proves the set of $\mu^{*}$-measurable sets, denoted here by $\sigma(\mu^{*})$ is a complete $\sigma$-algebra in which the restriction $\mu^{*}$ to it is a measure. Here, complete means that $\sigma(\mu^{*})$ contains all null sets, where a null set is defined as follows.

**Definition:** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. A set $N\subseteq \Omega$ is called a null set (with respect to $\mu$) if there exists $\tilde{N}\in \mathcal{F}$ with $N \subseteq \tilde{N}$ and $\mu(\tilde{N}) = 0$.

As mentioned before, $\sigma(\mu^{*})$ is complete by Carathéodory's Theorem. It means that it contains all null sets. But suppose $N \subseteq X$ is such that its outer measure $\mu^{*}(N) = 0$. Does it imply $N \in \sigma(\mu^{*})$?

**Add:** For completeness, if $A \subseteq X$:
$$\mu^{*}(A) := \inf\{\sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mu_{0}(A_{n}): \hspace{0.1cm} \mbox{$A \subseteq \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}}A_{n}$, $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) A_{n}\in \mathcal{A}$}\}$$

Comment: What is your definition of the outer measure? Is it in terms of countable covers of the set by sets in $\mathcal{A}$?

Comment: If that's the case, then your set is contained in a countable intersection of countable covers of it, where the measure of the cover converges to zero.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon I edited the post.

Comment: so it's answered in the previous comment.

Comment: @JunekeyJeon I don't know if I got it from your previous comment. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: So $N$ is contained in the countable intersection of sets of the form $B_{k}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n,k}$ whose measure is at most $1/k$. Thus you can take $\tilde{N}$ to be $\bigcap_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{k}$, which is in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and whose measure is zero. Or, are you not requiring your $\mathcal{F}$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra? In any case, Mason's answer shows that $N$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu^*(N) = 0$. To show that $N$ is $\mu^*$ measurable, we need to check that for any set $Y \subset \Omega$,
$$\mu^*(Y) \geq \mu^*(Y \cap N) + \mu^*(Y \cap N^c).$$
We have $\mu^*(Y \cap N) \leq \mu^*(N) = 0$ and $\mu^*(Y \cap N^c) \leq \mu^*(Y)$ by monotonicity, so $N$ is indeed measurable.